# How would you display an output like top

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py which displays the memory used in linux, I want the script to display the output like top, which automatically changes when a new process uses high memory.

I wrote a while loop with a time delay but that still does not display as top.

Any ideas?

Edit: Solved http://techarena51.com/index.php/watch-command-linux/

thx @stark

Comment: Are you looking for `ncurses`?

Comment: Create a loop and do polling.

Comment: look up `tput` commands

Comment: @triplee, I am looking to understand how top works, tput seems more for changing colors and cursor positions, not looking for that

Comment: watch cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: thnx stark, @sawa checkint that out as well

Comment: This seems too work `watch sudo command`

Comment: The point is that `top` moves the cursor around and draws over the old information at set intervals - which is how it seems to refresh without scrolling

Comment: If you solved it, you should answer you question and accept it as soon as you can in order not to let it without answer. But please, add some explaination of what is behind the link in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the watch command in bash

`watch commandname` or `watch sudo ps_pem.py`

The watch command will periodically run the command and display an output similar to top. You can view the same at http://techarena51.com/index.php/watch-command-linux/